# Inserting values from DataGridView to mysql table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried with many cases but not getting proper result.
I have one DataGridView and Button,

I have one table which contains 5 columns, In my windows application i will give 3 column values and 2 column values I want to get from datagridview and insert to mysql table.

In the run time, I will insert values to datagridview when i clicked on the button i want to get all values from datagridview to string or string array. Then i will insert to mysql table

```
con = new MySqlConnection(str);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandText = "insert into balance values" + "(@i1,@i2,@i3,@i4,@i5)";
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@i1", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@i2", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@i3", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@i4", MySqlDbType.Float);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@i5", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            //cmd.Parameters["@i1"].Value = busname;
            //cmd.Parameters["@i2"].Value = cusname;
            //cmd.Parameters["@i3"].Value = this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value;
            //cmd.Parameters["@i4"].Value = this.dataGridView1[1, 0].Value;
            //cmd.Parameters["@i5"].Value = "345";
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string[] st = new string[this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i <= this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {                    
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into balance values" + "(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", MySqlDbType.Float);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = busname;
                cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = cusname;
                cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = this.dataGridView1[0, i].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@p4"].Value = this.dataGridView1[1, i].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@p5"].Value = "345";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                     

            }
```

If I use the insert option within the for loop then I am getting error as

```
Parameter '@p1' has already been defined. same error for '@p2', '@p5' also.
```

I tried without using the for loop, which I commented. That is working fine. It is inserting into table also. But I don't know whats wrong when I am using with the for loop.

Comment: You are getting an error because you don't clear the command parameters. Adding `cmd.Parameters.Clear` before the cmd.CommandText = ... could fix the problem.